# How to use jbutton to make an jlabel to appear and disappear right away after releasing the click in JAVA

Tags: java, jbutton

As the title says, I would like to know the syntax for that

I am making a first person boxing game when you click the button it punches the enemy but after releasing it, the image of the punch disappears right away.

the concept of the game is how many click the user can make in a certain period of time

I don't have a code to show because its blank inside the button

Comment: "I don't have code because..." is **never** a valid argument.

Comment: JButton btnPunch = new JButton("");
btnPunch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
});

here's my code

Comment: ~shakes head in desperation~

Comment: you see I'm just asking how to make a jlabel to appear and disappear with one click

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
JButton btnPunch = new JButton("");
btnPunch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnPunch.setVisible(btnPunch.isVisible() ? false : true);
    }
});
```

If you want an action to be done *On Release* use:

```
addMouseListener(new 

MouseAdapter() { 
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
 { // TODO: add your code here
 } });
```

Comment: thanks but I want to know the syntax for when you click it once it appears and when you remove your finger it disappears

that code helps a lot too though

Comment: When you click it once it appears? Where do you click if it is not visible? I can't understand you...

Comment: think of it like tap titans. you punch when you push the button the animation will setVisible(true) but when you release the press on your mouse it disappear

Comment: [link] https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t34.0-12/12366659_883932011726973_973006107_n.jpg?oh=c19270253434b60c7e05c2580d56c818&oe=566C6C28 [/link]

this is the problem I want to make it disappear after I release the left click

Comment: I helped all that i could, provided you didn't actually attempt anything. Good luck.